# android SurfaceView в Dialog

Tags: android, камера

Подскажите, можно ли реализовать работу с камерой через SurfaceVeiw в Dialog. Есть некий код работы с камерой с SurfaceView, для Activity он прекрасно работает.

```
class A extends Activity implements...{
   ...
}
```

Но если поменять **Activity** на **Dialog**, программа "крашится" вот на этом участке кода.

```
class A extends Dialog implements ... {
   ...

@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); // crash here
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: программа всегда крашится со стактрейсом. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, перестаньте скрывать его от нас.

Comment: 06-18 18:57:44.934: E/test(22361): Exception
06-18 18:57:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 18:57:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
06-18 18:57:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:656)
06-18 18:57:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
06-18 18:57:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java

Comment: вопрос уже решен

Comment: what was the solution? I am facing a similar badtokenexception